# Google Fonts provides a single woff2 but webfonts-helper and github provide dozens of woff2 files, why is that?

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

I'm looking to host some fonts locally, which I've previously been using from Google Fonts.
I notice all the help articles point to [google-webfonts-helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) but the outcome is quite different.  With Google Fonts, a single woff2 file was being downloaded, but with the alternatives, there's a different woff2 being downloaded for each font weight.  That isn't great for performance/bandwidth and I'd like to reduce the number of requests being made.

Taking Montserrat font as an example, have a look at the CSS from Google Fonts.

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700

Notice how all the weights for Latin point at the same woff2 file.

```
src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v25/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wlhyw.woff2) format('woff2');
```

[image: google fonts css screenshot]

However if you go to Google-Webfonts-Helper, notice in the downloaded zip, there's a woff2 for each weight.

[image: google-webfonts-helper css example]

Further if you go to the [source Github repo](https://github.com/JulietaUla/Montserrat/tree/master/fonts/webfonts), it's the same there, different files for each weight.

[image: montserrat github repo]

What is Google Fonts doing differently that google-webfonts-helper and the others aren't?

And further, is there any harm in downloading that woff2 to use locally instead of what google-webfonts-helper gives?

Comment: You figured this out? Why does nobody answer this? I'm looking for a way to combine multiple subsets into one, and it seems like a perfect task for google webfonts helper. Not much help.

Comment: @brgs I didn't figure out why and I can't find any helpful information. They're different files and  I've gone ahead and used the single woff2 that I downloaded from Google Fonts instead of the helper tool. They're doing _something_ to make their single woff2 contain everything needed, and keeping it lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

If they are serving up one woff2 file that has multiple weights, then what they're serving up is a variable font.

A variable font with a weight axis contains glyph outlines for one weight plus delta data that describes how the outline control points for each glyph vary for other weights. In that way, the single variable font can support multiple different weights—in fact, a continuous range of weights.

If you check out the [Montserat repo in GitHub](https://github.com/googlefonts/Montserrat/tree/master/fonts), you'll see that you can get a single variable (two including italic) or you can get nine separate non-variable fonts

Comment: Oh I [see what you mean](https://github.com/googlefonts/Montserrat/tree/master/fonts/variable) but how come the font files in Github are 400+ kb, but if you go straight to [one of the woff2](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v25/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wdhyzbi.woff2) from the css, it's only 20-30 kb? It still seems that these variable font files are missing or not shared or somewhere else? Sorry if I use wrong terminology, this isn't a familiar area for me

Comment: The Google Font service can subset fonts for limiting Unicode character ranges. I'm not sure what parameters you're using and if that might be a factor.